# Remove Edit Delete Button When Exporting GridView To Excel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I Have GridView in ASP.Net application with AutoGenerateDeleteButton & AutoGenerateEditButton Set to True. I want when exporting gridview to excel to not show these button in excel sheet. My export code below:

```
    Private Sub ExportGridView()
    Dim attachment As String = "attachment; filename=FileName.xls"
    Response.ClearContent()
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment)
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"
    Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter
    Dim frm As HtmlForm = New HtmlForm()
    Page.EnableViewState = False
    Dim htw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    frm.Attributes("runat") = "server"
    Controls.Add(frm)

    gvResults.AllowPaging = False
    gvResults.AllowSorting = False
    BindGrid()

    gvResults.DataBind()
    gvResults.Columns(14).Visible = False
    gvResults.Columns(15).Visible = False
    gvResults.Columns(16).Visible = False
    frm.Controls.Add(gvResults)
    frm.RenderControl(htw)
    Response.Write(sw.ToString())
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seraching i came up with this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=User.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.AllowSorting = false;
        GridView1.Columns[14].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[15].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[16].Visible = false;
        BindGird();
        GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
        foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                cell.CssClass = "textmode";
            }
        }

        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        GridView1.Dispose();
    }
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}
```

and on aspx page make change like

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false"%>
```

in vb i guess it look like this

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Response.Clear
    Response.Buffer = true
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=User.xls")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Dim sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter
    Dim hw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false
    GridView1.AllowSorting = false
    GridView1.Columns(14).Visible = false
    GridView1.Columns(15).Visible = false
    GridView1.Columns(16).Visible = false
    BindGird
    GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White
    For Each cell As TableCell In GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells
        cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor
    Next
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        row.BackColor = Color.White
        For Each cell As TableCell In row.Cells
            If ((row.RowIndex Mod 2)  _
                        = 0) Then
                cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor
            Else
                cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor
            End If
            cell.CssClass = "textmode"
        Next
    Next
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
    'style to format numbers to string
    Dim style As String = "<style> .textmode { } </style>"
    Response.Write(style)
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString)
    Response.Flush
    Response.End
    GridView1.Dispose
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)

End Sub
```

.aspx page is like this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false"%>
```

Comment: This didn't work since they are not exactly first column  they are built in column I tried this first but didn't work

Comment: try to show gvreseult.Columns(14).Visible=true; after Response.End() and same for other columns

Comment: 14,15,16 are different columns I don't want to export them either. My problem is I don't want to show the Edit & Delete links in Excel which they appear in gridview after enabling the AutoGenerateDeleteButton & AutoGenerateEditButton

Comment: this solution run on my machine

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set them false when exporting:

```
    gvResults.AllowPaging = False
    gvResults.AllowSorting = False
    gvResults.AutoGenerateEditButton = False
    gvResults.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = False
    BindGrid()
```